# Testing isomorphism of simple field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, ring-isomorphism

Let $F$ be an **arbitrary** field, $f$ and $g$ irreducible polynomials over $F$. Consider the fields $F[x]/(f(x))$ and $F[y]/(g(y))$. Is there an algorithm to check whether these extensions are isomorphic?

Obviously the polynomials are to have the same degree. Maybe it is somehow possible to "naturally" embed both fields into a larger one and find the basis of their compositum or intersection using something similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4364044)?

Comment: It is necessary and sufficient that either $f(x)$ have a root in $F[y]/g(y)$ or vice versa. I don't know if there's an algorithm to check this in general but it should be checkable over, say, $\mathbb{Q}$, at least.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan It is indeed testable over $\Bbb Q$ and number fields (via the MSE link, as minpoly can be found using Lenstra factorization), finite fields (trivial). I'd just like to avoid factoring $g$ over $F(\overline{x})$ (apparently there are fields where you can't check irreducibility). I wonder if some forgotten technology like resultants might be of help.